# Using OneNote offline

Tags: onenote

I'm new to Windows Phone 8.1. It is a Nokia Lumia 635. I have no data plan, just use wifi.  Can I access OneNote notes that are saved on my phone if I am somewhere where there is no wifi such as checking a shopping list at a grocery store.  And I assume sync only happens when I on wifi.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can access OneNote notes even on offilne mode though you can access only upto last synchronized notes.

If you have made all the notes on your phone itself then all the notes will be available and if you have made notes through your PC's OneNote App then you have to synchronize it with your phone.